Shimano 105 thru-axle freehub FH-R7070: freewheel body servicability and separately orderable?
I'm searching for a replacement freewheel body for my bike.
The only marking on my freewheel body is
18-d-3 11S

Internet search did not yield useful results for this string.
Searching for Shimano hubs yielded this one:

https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/shimano105-r7000/FH-R7070.html
The numbering "R7070" is very similar to that of the other parts. The hub and freewheel body looks very much like this, it might very well be exactly this one.
According to the dealers manual,

the freewheel body itself has no part number
is not serviceable


Do not attempt to disassemble the freewheel body, because it may result in a malfunction.

Questions

Although not documented, is there a freewheel body part that fits?
Is the serviceability note only the typical liability disclaimer or is it truly hard to service?

(Note 20yrs ago I disassembled and reassembled a freewheel body with no problems and there are maintenance guides for current freewheel body out there.)

Whilst the freehub may not be serviceable, it does appear that a replacement is available, the part number that you want is either Y0CK98040 (with washer) or Y0CK98050 (without)
For example https://www.cyclebasket.com/m9b0s702p3818/Shimano_Y0CK98040_FHR7070_Freehub_Body
